# Please suggest error in this program for level order tree traversal

Tags: c++, tree

Please suggest error in this program for level order tree traversal
I am getting an infinite loop all printing 1

Algorithm:

For each node, first the node is visited and then it’s child nodes are put in a FIFO queue.

printLevelorder(tree)

```
1.Create an empty queue q
2.temp_node = root /*start from root*/
3.Loop while temp_node is not NULL
a) print temp_node->data.
b) Enqueue temp_node’s children (first left then right children) to q
c) Dequeue a node from q and assign it’s value to temp_node


#include<iostream>
```

This is the node for tree

```
struct node
{
struct node *left;
int data;
struct node *right;
};
```

This is node for queue to hold the node of tree

```
struct qnode
{
struct node *node;
struct qnode *next;
};

struct frontandrear
{
struct qnode *front;
struct qnode *rear;
};


struct node* newNode( int data )
{
struct node *new_node = (struct node*)malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
new_node->data = data;
new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
return new_node;
}



void enQueue( struct frontandrear *fr, struct node* node )
{
struct qnode* new_node = (struct qnode*)malloc( sizeof( struct qnode ) );
new_node->node = node;

if (fr->rear == NULL)
    {
    new_node->next = NULL;
    fr->rear = new_node;
    fr->front = new_node;

    }
else
    {
    new_node->next = fr->rear;
    fr->rear = new_node;
    }
}

struct node* deQueue( struct frontandrear *fr )
{
if (fr->front == NULL)
    {
    return NULL;
    }
struct node* num = fr->front->node;
fr->front = fr->front->next;

if (fr->front == NULL)
    {
    fr->front = fr->rear = NULL;
    }
return num;
}

void printLevelOrder( struct node* root )
{
struct frontandrear *frontandrear = (struct frontandrear*)malloc( sizeof(     struct frontandrear ) );
frontandrear->front = frontandrear->rear = NULL;

struct node *temp = root;

while (temp != NULL)
    {
    printf( "%d\t", root->data );
    if (temp->left)
        enQueue( frontandrear, root->left );
    if (temp->right)
        enQueue( frontandrear, root->right );
    temp = deQueue( frontandrear );
    }
}


int main( )
{

struct node *root = newNode( 1 );
root->left = newNode( 2 );
root->right = newNode( 3 );
root->left->left = newNode( 4 );
root->left->right = newNode( 5 );

printf( "Level Order traversal of binary tree is \n" );
printLevelOrder( root );
}
```

Comment: The right tool to use here is a debugger.  Here is a good link to learn how to debug a simple program: [Debugging a Simple Program](http://www.wikihow.com/Debug-a-C%2B%2B-Program)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I didnt know that it is possible to have an object of the same name as a class. I find it rather confusing. Also when you declare a struct you dont need to write `struct`, e.g. `struct node *temp = root;` is just `node* temp = root;`

Comment: Besides the `#include <iostream>` (which doesn't seem to actually be in code) this looks like entirely C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop here:

```
while (temp != NULL)
    {
    printf( "%d\t", root->data );
    if (temp->left)
        enQueue( frontandrear, root->left );
    if (temp->right)
        enQueue( frontandrear, root->right );
    temp = deQueue( frontandrear );
    }
}
```

In the second arguments to `enQueue`, you are using `root` where I think you meant to use `temp`.